# LINQ select with more than one condition using OR

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am going to pass a List to the linq for searching

for example:

```
List<string> test = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d"}
var list = db.table.where(t => t.testName.Contains(test)).toList;
```

I hope I can select all the record which testName is a / b / c / d. In SQL statement, it should be

```
select * from table where testName = 'a' OR testName = 'b' OR testName = 'c' OR testNmae = 'd'
```

In real program, the list will be dynamic so can ensure the size will be 1 or 99.

but when I try to use .Contains it will throw error that Contains cannot convert List to string.

Comment: `var list = db.table.where(t =>test.Contains(t.testName)).toList();` ?

Answer (score 1):

you have a `List<string>`, and you are wanting to test a column to see if it, a `string`, contains a substring that matches any in your `List`.  So try

```
var list = db.table.Where(t => test.Any(t.testName.Contains)).ToList();
```

if you want to check if any are actually equal, then use

```
var list = db.table.Where(t => test.Any(tt => t.testName == tt)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to give us the type of `db.Table`, but it seems that it returns a sequence of similar objects, where every object has a string property `TestName`.
To make the discussion easier, let's say that your table contains `Tests`, every row of the table is one `Test`, every `Test` has a string property `TestName`.

**Requirement** given a sequence of strings, give me all Tests from the table that have a TestName that equals one of the elements in the sequence of strings.

In your code `db.table.where(t =>` every t is one Test.

So you want to keep only those Tests, that have a name in your sequence of strings:

```
var requiredTestNames = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d"};
var testsWithRequiredTestName = db.Table
    .Where(test => requiredTestNames.Contains(test.TestName))
    .ToList();
```

In words:

I have a sequence of required test names. From the table filled with tests, keep only those tests, that have a value test.TestName that is in requiredTestNames.

By the way: did you see that by using identifiers that describe what they mean, proper use of singular and plural nouns, the code is much better readable, and looks much more similar to your requirement?